# mysql_num_rows() returns 0 and I can't figure out why

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I don't know where the problem is, that `mysql_num_rows()` always returns 0.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE banned='0'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    die("INTERNAL SERVER ERROR!");
}

while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
    if(count($array) == 0) { 
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $array['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $array['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $array['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $array['pont'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $array['rang'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>Bann!</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

}
```

My code always returns:

> INTERNAL SERVER ERROR!

Why does always my query fails? What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1. *Always error appaears* What error do you get? 2. What is the current output and what would you expect it to be?

Comment: Error: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR!
The problem is that you can not retrieve the data from the table, and I think all is well inside

Comment: First of all dont use mysql_* they are depricated. use mysqli_* or PDO. second try to get correct error . just after query write or die(mysql_error('your database connection object')). and also put your full code.

Comment: @Brandx Please make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: try `!mysql_num_rows($result)` instead of `mysql_num_rows($result) == 0`

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` returns `FALSE` on failure, which would be `==` to 0. So either there's something wrong with your query and you're not grabbing the error message first, or there really are no results (we can't possibly know which).

Comment: ^^ Zero rows returned is _not an error state_, so you should not report an error there.

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Well since your code doesn't work and you use `mysql_*` which is deprecated I think it's the best opportunity to change your code to [`mysqli_* prepared statement`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or to [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), *they are much safer*.

So your code would look something like this:

```
<?php

    $databaseHost = "localhost";
    $databaseName = "DBNAME";
    $databaseUser = "root";
    $databasePass = "";

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $databaseHost .";dbname=" . $databaseName, $databaseUser, $databasePass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE banned=:bannedState");
        $stmt->execute(["bannedState" => 0]);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>

<table border='1'>
<?php

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
            echo "<td>No Data</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['pont'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['rang'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>Bann!</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }   
    }

?>
</table>
```

**Side notes:**

Add [`error reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s) to get useful error messages:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Have error reporting on only while staging, never in production!

Comment: Please explain downVote, so that I can improve my answer!

Comment: imo the parameter `id` should have another name though, plus your forgot an `:` in the `execute` array. (`$stmt->execute([":id" => 0]);`)

Comment: @DarkBee agree with the name (will change it); But the colon isn't necessary, it also works without it

Comment: Did not know that.. Funny because i'm always hesistant when coding from scratch wether to add it or not. (I did not downvote this for the record)